# Poderia me ajudar porque nao remove da lista?

Tags: java

#### Minha interface

```
public interface RepositoryProdutos {
    public void Listartodos(Produtos produtos);
    public void Salvar(Produtos produtos);
    public void remover(Produtos produtos);
}
```

#### Classe que implementa o metodo da interface

```
@Override       
public void remover(Produtos produtos) {
    System.out.println("Removendo .......");
    List<Produtos> produto = new ArrayList<Produtos>();
    produto.remove(produtos);   
}
```

#### Classe principal

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Produtos prod1 = new Produtos();
    Produtos prod2 = new Produtos(2, "veve");
    ProdutosImplementado pi = new ProdutosImplementado();
    ProdutosImplementado p2 = new ProdutosImplementado();

    prod1.setCodigo(1);
    prod1.setNome("teste");

    pi.Salvar(prod1);
    p2.Salvar(prod2);

    pi.Listartodos(prod1);
    p2.Listartodos(prod2);

    p2.remover(prod2);

    p2.Listartodos(prod2);
}
```

E aqui é a saida no terminal:

```
Salvando Produtos... de [codigo = 1, nome = teste]
Salvando Produtos... de [codigo = 2, nome = veve]
Listando Produtos... de [codigo = 1, nome = teste]
Listando Produtos... de [codigo = 2, nome = veve]
Removendo ......
Listando Produtos... de [codigo = 2, nome = veve]
```

Por que o objeto `p2` nao foi removido?

Comment: Se eu colocar o pi.remover(prod1) também nao remove, o que está de errado nesse código??

Comment: As pessoas estão chutando respostas porque a pergunta não está clara. Faça um [mcve] para ajudar as pessoas darem repostas que servem para ajudar.

Comment: Seu método `remover` esta inicializando uma lista vazia e tentando remover o elemento dela (esse código não faz nada na prática). Você deve remover o elemento da mesma lsita em que voce o persistiu (método `salvar`). PS: Por convenção métodos em Java começam com letra minúscula.

Comment: Anthony Accioly como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Não remove da lista, simplesmente porque você não implementou os metodos hashCode e Equals do objeto, ou esta feito de forma errada.

Dessa forma a lista não acha o objeto para ser removido.

Implemente os metodos hashCode e Equals em Produtos

Abaixo uma dica de teste, adicione uns 3 produto na liste e teste.

```
List<Produtos> produto = new ArrayList<Produtos>();
int indice=produto.indexOf(seuProdutoTeste);
System.out.println(indice);
```

- Ele deve imprimir o índice correto, do seu objeto, esse é o teste para garantir que seu **metodos hashCode e Equal do objeto Produtos** esteja correto.
- Geralmente não se usa nome de objetos no plural.

Montei um exemplo ai: veja, teste, tire as suas conclusões

```
package com;
public interface IProduto
{
}

package com;
public class Produto  implements IProduto
{
    private Long id;

    public Produto(Long id)
    {
        this.id=id;
    }

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
        {
            return true;
        }
        Produto other = (Produto) obj;
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass() || (id == null && other.id != null) || !id.equals(other.id))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

package com;

public class Milho extends Produto
{
    private String nome;

    public Milho(Long id, String nome)
    {
        super(id);
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome()
    {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + ((nome == null) ? 0 : nome.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        if (this == obj)
        {
            result = true;
        }
        if (obj instanceof Milho)
        {
            Milho other = (Milho) obj;
            if (!(!super.equals(obj) || getClass() != obj.getClass() || (nome == null && other.nome != null)
                    || !nome.equals(other.nome)))
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}




import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TesteRemoveList
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TesteRemoveList test = new TesteRemoveList();
        test.testRemoveIProduto();
        test.testRemoveProduto();
        test.testRemoveMilho();
    }

    public void testRemoveMilho()
    {
        System.out.println("--------------------");
        final List<Milho> produtos = new ArrayList<Milho>();
        produtos.add(new Milho(2L, "Amarelo"));
        produtos.add(new Milho(3L, "Verde"));
        produtos.add(new Milho(4L, "Cozido"));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());

        //vamos remover o 2 
        produtos.remove(new Produto(2L));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());
        produtos.remove(new Produto(2L));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());
        //não acha
        produtos.remove(new Milho(2L, "Verde"));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());
        //acha
        produtos.remove(new Milho(2L, "Amarelo"));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());
        //não acha mais
        produtos.remove(new Milho(2L, "Amarelo"));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());
        System.out.println("--------------------");
    }

    public void testRemoveIProduto()
    {
        System.out.println("--------------------");
        final List<IProduto> produtos = new ArrayList<IProduto>();
        produtos.add((IProduto) new Produto(1L));
        produtos.add((IProduto) new Produto(2L));
        produtos.add((IProduto) new Milho(2L, "Amarelo"));
        produtos.add((IProduto) new Milho(3L, "Verde"));
        produtos.add((IProduto) new Milho(4L, "Cozido"));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());
        //vamos remover o 2 
        produtos.remove(new Produto(2L));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());
        produtos.remove(new Produto(2L));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());
        //não acha
        produtos.remove(new Milho(2L, "Verde"));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());
        //acha
        produtos.remove(new Milho(2L, "Amarelo"));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());
        //não acha mais
        produtos.remove(new Milho(2L, "Amarelo"));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());
        System.out.println("--------------------");
    }

    public void testRemoveProduto()
    {
        System.out.println("--------------------");
        final List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<Produto>();
        produtos.add(new Produto(1L));
        produtos.add(new Produto(1L));
        produtos.add(new Produto(1L));
        produtos.add(new Produto(2L));
        produtos.add(new Produto(3L));
        produtos.add(new Produto(4L));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());
        //encontrou um removeu
        produtos.remove(new Produto(1L));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());
        produtos.remove(new Produto(1L));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());
        produtos.remove(new Produto(1L));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());
        produtos.remove(new Produto(1L));
        System.out.println(produtos.size());
        System.out.println("--------------------");
    }
}
```

É só copiar o código e ajustar o pacote e testar, ele esta bem evoluido

Comment: eu implementei na classe produtos, tanto para o atributo codigo, como nome, vale mencionar que esse exemplo apenas para fins educacionais nao faz persistência.

Comment: Não importa se precisa persistir ou não é requisito da interface List, precisa estar correto esse métodos para isso funcione, se hasCode do objeto for encontrado e ele equals estive correto ele vai remover,

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo, agora não terás mais duvida.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, amigo.

Seu algoritmo está correto. Entretanto o compilador precisa saber o que difere um objeto Produtos de outro objeto Produtos.

Você precisa sobrescrever o método equals da classe Produtos. Por default, toda classe Java extend a classe Object.

Exemplo:

Se o nome de um obj1 for igual ao nome de um obj2, caracteriza igualdade entre eles.

É exatamente isso que você vai precisar faze:

Identificar o que torna o obj único e implementar a lógica no método equals.